Is this a possible definition for the Levi-Civita connection coefficients?
Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a Riemannian manifold. Let $(U,x)$ be the Riemann normal coordinates about some chart $U$. Let $(U,y)$ be some arbitrary coordinates. Define $D := x(U) \cap y(U) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and the transition mapping $\varphi := y \circ x^{-1}:D \to D$. Let $\{e_i\} \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be the standard basis vectors.
So, $(D,\varphi)$ defines a curvilinear coordinate system, in the usual Euclidean sense. Let $\partial_i \in TD$ be a differential operator field over $D$, defined as $\partial_i|_p(f) := \frac{d}{dt} (f \circ \varphi^{-1})(\varphi(p) + t e_i)|_{t=0}$, where $p \in D$ and $f:D \to \mathbb{R}$ is any smooth function.
Next, we'll define the coordinate basis (which will be a set of linearly independent vector fields) induced by $(D,\varphi)$ as follows. Set $\tilde{e}_i|_p := \frac{d}{dt} \varphi^{-1}(\varphi(p) + te_i)|_{t=0} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Now, since we're in Euclidean space, $\partial_j|_p(\tilde{e}_i) = \frac{d}{dt}(\tilde{e}_i \circ \varphi^{-1})(\varphi(p) + te_i)|_{t=0}$ is well-defined, and is a vector. Then, we can write $\partial_j|_p(\tilde{e}_i) = \Gamma_{ij}^k(p) \tilde{e}_k|_p$ for some unique $\Gamma_{ij}^k(p) \in \mathbb{R}$. My question is, do these $\{\Gamma_{ij}^k\}$ functions coincide with the Levi-Civita connection coefficients?

How do your $\Gamma^k_{ij}$ have anything to do with the Riemannian metric on $\mathcal M$?

They are induced by $\varphi = y^{-1} \circ x$, where $x:U \to x(U)$ is the Riemann normal coordinates.

But $y$ is arbitrary. This seems totally random to me. Calculate it in the simplest $2$-dimensional examples.

@TedShifrin the idea is it’s the christoffel symbols induced by the chart (U,y), provided this is all correct.

It’s incumbent on you to prove your claim. I see nothing to make me begin to believe it. You should include in your argument precisely what you mean by Riemann normal coordinates; there are at least two standard meanings for that.
